# Qt5 - QBoxLayout Piling Everything on Top of Each Other

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm trying to learn about Qt and I'm having trouble understanding layouts.  No matter what I do, it's just piling everything on top of each other and not actually laying anything out.

This is just to sort of get something together for me to get a format going, but what I'm going after is this - Three widgets that are a button above and below a layer field, and underneath these three widgets are two input and output textedit fields.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    setWindowTitle(config::kDisplay_name);

    input_field_ = new QTextEdit(this);
    input_field_->setPlaceholderText("Input");
    input_field_->setMinimumSize(this->width(), 200);

    output_field_ = new QTextEdit(this);
    output_field_->setPlaceholderText("Output");
    output_field_->setReadOnly(true);
    output_field_->setMinimumSize(this->width(), 200);

    connect(input_field_, &QTextEdit::textChanged,
            this, &MainWindow::UpdateOutputText);

    rotorR_ = new RotorSlot(this);
    rotorC_ = new RotorSlot(this);
    rotorL_ = new RotorSlot(this);

    rotor_layout_ = new QHBoxLayout();
    rotor_layout_->addWidget(rotorR_);
    rotor_layout_->addWidget(rotorC_);
    rotor_layout_->addWidget(rotorL_);

    layout_ = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout_->addLayout(rotor_layout_);
    layout_->addWidget(input_field_);
    layout_->addWidget(output_field_);
    
}
```

```
RotorSlot::RotorSlot(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent) {

    window_ = new QLabel(this);
    window_->setFont(QFont("Courier", 24, 75));
    window_->setText("A");
    window_->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    window_->setFixedSize(50, 50);

    up_ = new QPushButton("^", this);
    up_->setFixedSize(50, 50);
    down_ = new QPushButton("v", this);
    down_->setFixedSize(50, 50);

    layout_ = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout_->addWidget(up_);
    layout_->addWidget(window_);
    layout_->addWidget(down_);
}
```

[No matter what I do, I get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c9yH.png)

If I add `setLayout(layout_);` to my `MainWindow` constructor I just get an error about how there's already a layout assigned.

What I've written all seems consistent with the examples in the Qt documentation, so what have I missed?  What's going on?

Comment: You're misusing `QMainWindow`.  You need to create and set its content using [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to assign a layout to a widget is to pass the widget in the layout's constructor:

```
RotorSlot::RotorSlot(QWidget *parent) {
  // Set up widgets [...]
  
  // layout_ should lay out this widget
  layout_ = new QVBoxLayout(this);

  // Add things to layout [...]
}
```

However, a `QMainWindow` is a bit of a special case. It has a built-in default layout, that handles menus, statusbar, dockers, etc. In that case, you would create a dummy widget and set it as the window's central widget:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {

   // Set everything up [...]

   // Dummy widget
   QWidget *w = new QWidget(this);
   // Layout
   layout_ = new QVBoxLayout(w);
   // Set as central widget
   this->setCentralWidget(w);

   // Add things to layout [...]
}
```

Comment: This is awesome; thanks.

And as to how nested layouts seem to work, it looks like I was initializing and adding things to them all in the wrong order.